# taxi fare calculation using php with google distance matrix api v2

Tags: php, math, calculator, google-maps-api-2

I want to have a taxi fare calculation in my website.

I have the following requirements:

If Google Distance Matrix calculation show following distance kilometers, the rate should go like this:

- From 0 -10km = $65 (fixed price) + 11%
- 10km = $70 + 11%
- 15km = $80 + 11%
- 20km = $90 + 11%
- 25km = $100 + 11%
- 30km = $120 + 11%
- 30km above = $4 / km

I put rate as $2 per km from 10 km above till 30km + $50  extra which result :

if taxi if drived for

- 20km = 20km × $2 + $50 = $90 + 11%
- 21km = 21km × $2 + $50 = $92 + 11%
- 22km = 22km × $2 + $50 = $94 + 11% and so on

but i am dont know to calculate the fixed price of $65 which is the fix rate for below 10 km distance and $120 rate for 30 km and 30km above ie $4/km .

the script i used for Google Distance Matrix is to show $2/km + $50 fix : (I have not added 11% in this script)

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=_MY_API_KEY" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php
$rate=2;
$extra=50;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;
    var map;
var gdir;
var geocoder = null;
var addressMarker;
var directionsPanel;
var directions;
    function initialize() {
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
            gDir = new GDirections();
            GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
                    var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
                    var drivingDistanceround = 
Math.round(drivingDistanceMiles*100)/100;
                    var cost = ((drivingDistanceMiles * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php 
echo $extra; ?>))
                    <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo 
$extra; ?>))
                    };
                    */
                    var fare=cost;
                    var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
                    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<table 
width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding-top:3px;"><tr><td rowspan="2" 
width="35"><img src="images/rates.png"></td><td><strong>Distance: </strong>' + 
drivingDistanceround + ' Kilemeters</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Estimated Cost: 
</strong>$ ' + fare + '</td></tr></table>';
            });
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {      
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-33.722626, 150.810585), 10);
    gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
    GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDimrectionsLoad);
    GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);

  }
}

function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress, locale) {
  gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress);


    }

    function showLocation() {
            geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].from.value, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                    {
                            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first 
address");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            location1 = {lat: 
response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: 
response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                            geocoder.getLocations(document.forms[0].to.value, function 
(response) {
                                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                                    {
                                            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode 
the second address");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            location2 = {lat: 
response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: 
response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                                            gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' 
to: ' + location2.address);
                                    }
                            });
                    }
            });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var directionsPanel;
var directions;

  directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
  directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
  directions.load("from: "+document.forms[0].from.value+" to: 
"+document.forms[0].to.value);

    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<table width="915" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FF9F0F" 
style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFF99" style="padding:10px;"><table width="905" border="0" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 914px; height: 480px; border: solid 1px 
#336699"></div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><div id="form" style="width: 904px; text-align:center; border: solid 1px 
#336699; background:#d1e1e4;">
      <form action="#" onsubmit="document.getElementById('route').innerHTML=''; 
showLocation(); setDirections(this.from.value, this.to.value); return false;">
        <p style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt;">From:
          <input id="fromAddress" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') 
this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) 
this.value='';" value="Street Name City, State" maxlength="50" size="26" name="from" 
style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt;" />
          To:
          <input id="toAddress" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') 
this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) 
this.value='';" value="Street Name City, State" maxlength="50" size="26" name="to" 
style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt;"/>
          <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" 
style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt;" />
        </p>
        <div id="results" style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt; text-align:left; 
padding-left:5px; padding-bottom:5px;"></div>
        <div id="route" style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:8pt; text-align:left; 
padding-left:5px; padding-bottom:5px;"></div>
    </form>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to go for **Google Maps API V3**, here is my tested script as per your requirement, and as per your earlier script, I would suggest to go for @Pierre-Francoys Brousse script for rates,

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $rate = 2;
    $extra = 50;
    $fix = 65;
    $above = 110;
    $next=55;
    $min=3;
    $cons = 4;
    //}
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Taxi Fare Calculation using PHP with GOOGLE MAPS API V3</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family:tahoma;
        font-size:8pt;
    }
    #total {
        font-size:large;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Georgia, “Times New Roman”, Times, serif;
        color:#990000;
        margin:5px 0 10px 0;
        font-size:12px;
        width:374px;
    }
    input {
        margin:5px 0px;
        font-family:tahoma;
        font-size:8pt;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
          var map = null;
          var directionDisplay;
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

          function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

            var Australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.085599,133.66699);

            var mapOptions = {  
                        center              : Australia,
                        zoom                : 4,
                        minZoom             : 3,
                        streetViewControl   : false,
                        mapTypeId           : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        zoomControlOptions  : {style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.MEDIUM}
                    };


            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);

             //Find From location    
        var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
        var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText);
        fromAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
        //Find To location
        var toText = document.getElementById('end');
        var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText);
        toAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
        //  
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

            /*var control = document.getElementById('control');
            control.style.display = 'block';
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);*/
          }

          function calcRoute() {
            var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
            var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
            var request = {
              origin: start,
              destination: end,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                computeTotalDistance(response);
              }
            });
          }
          function computeTotalDistance(result) {
          var total = 0;
          var myroute = result.routes[0];
          for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
          }
          total = total / 1000;
          /*Start Calculating Distance Fair*/
              if (10>total){
              var cost = <?php echo $fix; ?>;
              }
              else if (10<total && 20>total)
                {
                var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $extra; ?>));
                }
                else if (20<total && 30>total)
                {
                    var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $next; ?>));
                }
                else if (30<total && 50>total)
                {
                    var cost = (((total - 30) * <?php echo $cons; ?>) + (<?php echo $above; ?>));
                }
                else
                {
                    var cost = (((total - 50) * <?php echo $min; ?>) + 130);
                }

              var fare = cost * 0.11 + cost;
              var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
          /*Distance Fair Calculation Ends*/

          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Distance = " + total + " km and FARE = $" + fare;
          }

        function auto() {
        var input = document.getElementById[('start'), ('end')];
        var types
        var options = {
           types: [],
           componentRestrictions: {country: ["AUS"]}
            };
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
         }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="initialize()">
    <table width="380px" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FF9F0F" style="border-collapse:collapse">
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" style="padding:5px;">
        <table width="375px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 374px; height: 300px; border: solid 1px #336699"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><div id="form" style="width:374px; text-align:center; border: solid 1px #336699; background:#d1e1e4;">
                  From:
                    <input type="text" id="start" size="60px" name="start" placeholder="Enter Location From">
                    <br />
                    To:
                    <input size="60px" type="text" id="end" name="end" placeholder="Enter Destination ">
                    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcRoute();">
                 <div id="total"></div>
                 </div></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @roshanthapa your code is supreme, do you have any idea do make it with miles ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question how can you have a fix price or a varying 'rate', why don't you just an if/else or a [switch/case](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) logic? 
Also, why are you injecting php when this could be done in javascript?

Instead of

```
  var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
  var drivingDistanceround = Math.round(drivingDistanceMiles*100)/100;
  var cost = ((drivingDistanceMiles * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $extra; ?>))
  <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $extra; ?>))
```

Why not just do

```
var rate = 2;
var extra = 50;
taxModifier = 1.11; //11%
//...

var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
var drivingDistanceround = Math.round(drivingDistanceMiles*100)/100;
var cost;
if (drivingDistanceMiles < 10){ 
   cost = 65; 
} else if( drivingDistanceMiles >= 10 && drivingDistanceMiles < 30) {
    cost = (drivingDistanceMiles * rate + extra) * taxModifier ;
} else {
    cost = drivingDistanceMiles * 4. * taxModifier  ;
}
```